# Extract group of characters from an object/string

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a very long string of characters that contain a date and time. How can I extract just the date part and the time part from it?

Here's the string:
0:2019010309130000:0.000000:126:0

I just need to extract the date and the time as in:

Date - 20190103
Time - 0913 and format it as 09:13

Answer (score 0):

This applies to Python programming language.:

If the string stays in the same format I believe you should be able to extract it using a concept known as "slicing" (you can find more about it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)).

```
x = "0:2019010309130000:0.000000:126:0"
y = 'Date - {} Time - {}:{}'.format(x[2:10], x[10:12], x[12:14])
print(y)
```